# Parse.com PFUser signUpInBackgroundWithBlock: block not being called on first tap

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

i am developing an iOS-App with Swift and the parse.com framework and have a big problem with registering new users.

The block of "signUpInBackgroundWithBlock" is not being called on the first tap, although the new user is getting registered. When i am tapping the button a second time, the block gets finally called and i get an error, that the username is already registered.

```
var newUser = PFUser()
newUser.username = registerView.nicknameTextField.text.trim()
newUser.email = registerView.emailTextField.text
newUser.password = registerView.passwordTextField.text

newUser.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            self.registerCompletionBlock(succeeded, error: error)
    }
```

Is someone having the same problem and knows a solution for this strange behaviour?

Thanks!

Edit:

The completion block should call the "registerCompletionBlock()" function:

```
func registerCompletionBlock(succeeded: Bool, error: NSError!) {
    if error == nil {
        let subscriptionStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Subscription", bundle: nil)
        let viewcontroller: UIViewController = subscriptionStoryboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as UIViewController
        self.presentViewController(viewcontroller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        if let errorString = error.userInfo?["error"] as? NSString {
            println(errorString)
            if error.userInfo?["code"] as Float == 202{
                let alert = UIAlertView(title: "vergeben", message: "name vergeben", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "abbrechen")
                alert.show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its calling at first time, but its taking a little time for calling this .. because its sending data on server in asynchronous. Check with break point ..

Answer (score 1):

I tried the solution posted previously (eliminating `PFUser.enableAutomaticUser()`), and the issue persisted.

In case anyone else is still looking for a solution to this issue, try changing the `if error == nil` to `if succeeded == true` in the block of `signUpInBackground`. This worked for me and all is functional in backend.

Answer (score 0):

Its calling at first time, but its taking a little time for calling this .. because its sending data on server in asynchronous. Asynchronous never block the main thread..

Because : -

- **Asynchronous** never block the main thread waiting for a network response.
- **Asynchronous** can be either synchronous on a separate thread, or scheduled in the run loop of any thread.
- **Asynchronous** can be either synchronous on a separate thread, or scheduled in the run loop of any thread.
- **Synchronous** blocks main thread until they complete request.

Answer (score 0):

Because you call the method asynchronous, it takes some time to do it and your main thread doesn't wait for the method to finish. So you should, if you want to show a message or perform a segue, after the registration, put it inside the completion-block:

```
newUser.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (succeeded: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
      // Perform a segue, show a message or whatever you want

    } else {
      let errorString = error.userInfo["error"] as NSString
      // Show the errorString somewhere and let the user try again.
    }
  }
```

Also if you don't want to do it asynchronous, you can call the `signUp()` method(without the `inBackgroundWithBlock`. That way the application waits for the signup to finish until it continues.

Comment: Hi, i did the same by calling the function registerCompletionBlock within the block. I just outsourced it in an own function to keep the code cleaner. Is this wrong?

Comment: Sorry, my fault. No of course not. But I think the problem is, that it takes a while to signup depending on your internet connection. So you should for example block the button until it's done.

Comment: I think the internet connection isn't really the problem, because i am connected to an ethernet cable. Parse.com **does** sign me up (i can see the new user in the data browser dashboard of parse), thats not the problem, but my app **doesn't** run through the block, when it's done signing up.

Comment: I am having the same issue. The user gets signed up but the completion block never runs. I am only having this problem after upgrading to Xcode 7 and swift 2.0

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out. Problem was, that i used PFUser.enableAutomaticUser() in the AppDelegate. I removed that line and the signup-block works flawlessly now!