# Parse | Sign Up Block not being executed

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to sign up a user and it used to work perfectly before but now the code in the block is not being executed, I used breakpoints to figure it out.

```
user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (success: Bool, error: NSError?) in

            print("It works?")

           /* if success{

                print("Sign Up Succeeded")
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toMainView", sender: self)


            }else{

                print(error?.description, appendNewline: false)

            }*/
        }

    }
```

Note: I'm using Xcode 7 Beta.

Comment: what is your xcode version, check: println("\(success)")

Comment: I'm using Xcode 7 Beta

Comment: K @Haidous, Then try to print("\(error) & \(success)") and check if(error == nil)

Comment: The code is not even running

Comment: ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28540052/parse-com-pfuser-signupinbackgroundwithblock-block-not-being-called-on-first-ta

Comment: "Not even running" is a hint that user is probably nil. Breakpoint, or log the user before the signup code.